# How do I change the License Key on a PrePidded installation of Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, licensing

On one of my computers, I was using an old student copy of Visual Studio 2010. I have just purchased a full retail copy, do I need to uninstall my student copy and install my retail copy or is there a way to change the license key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you need to uninstall the old version and install the new one.